# Execute ajax only one time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I want only execute my ajax post 1 time, i try to avoid to the user refresh the page and execute so much times the ajax post,
I thought in create a cookies, but i don't know, and i'm no sure, somebody know how?

This is my jquery.

```
var t = jQuery.noConflict();
t( document ).ready(function() {
  t.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 }); // Sample 2
  console.log( "ready!" );
  alert(t.cookie("example"));
  var data = '<?php echo json_encode($json_full);?>';
  t.ajax({
    url: 'my api url', 
    type: 'POST', 
    success: function(r) { alert(JSON.stringify(r)) }, 
    dataType: 'JSON', 
    data: { data: data, }
  })
});
```

/**I need run this AJAX only one time because is a checkout page to send the order, and if i refresh the page, send every time the same order, and this i don't want**/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you sending an AJAX request on page load anyway? Why don't you just process the data on the server side before loading the page?

Comment: client-side order processing? that's something awfully exploitable. please forget about ajax and create a fraud-secure server-side code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will only work on IE8 and above, but you can use `localStorage`:

```
var t = jQuery.noConflict();
t( document ).ready(function() {
    t.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 }); // Sample 2
    console.log( "ready!" );
    alert(t.cookie("example"));

    if(localStorage['submitted'] === undefined){
        var data = '<?php echo json_encode($json_full);?>';
        t.ajax({
            url: 'my api url', 
            type: 'POST', 
            success: function(r) { 
                localStorage['submitted'] = true;
                alert(JSON.stringify(r));
            }, 
            dataType: 'JSON', 
            data: { data: data, }
        })
    }
});
```

This way the first time it will run the AJAX because you haven't set the `localStorage` variable, but upon success you do and it will not resubmit on page refresh.

If you wanted to have the ability to send again upon a future visit, just use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`. Same syntax and everything.

Comment: Couldn't this be bypassed with `localStorage.clear()`?

Comment: Do you know how i can make for hide this functions from the firebug, of the browsers?

Comment: @Deimos - you can make it "harder" by obfusication (something like [uglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)) but you can't hide it completely.

Comment: You know the thankyoupage.php?order=1878&key=order_52e90da8e878b is like that, and only one time i want to send the ajax, but if the user order another product will have thankyoupage.php?order=1878&key=order_5459439534958349583495839485934 another url id so should be work again the ajax can you understand, sorry hehe

Comment: @Deimos - the answer i provided was based on the example you gave. considering the situation that you are describing, i don't think AJAX on page load is the best way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Things like these can not be safely controlled on the client's browser. Any user with minimal knowledge in JavaScript will be able to open up the developers tools for their browser and manipulate the code or any values you might have stored (such as deleting the cookie you have set).

This limitation should be implemented on the server.

---

It really depends on the scope of your application. You might be able to limit the requests per IP address, but that might prevent multiple people from the same office for example loading the page at the same time.

Using user authentication and persistent server storage you'll be able to limit the effect of the request, but you probably won't be able to prevent the actual request from being sent as anyone can make that request even from outside the browser. You could store the user_id of the user that initiated the request and only allow the resulting action to occur if a certain time has passed since the last request.

Comment: And your suggestion lix? can you explain me please the best way

Comment: @Deimos - it really depends on the scope of your application. You might be able to limit the requests per IP address, but that might prevent multiple people from the same office for example loading the page at the same time. Without full user authentication and persistent server storage it'll be quite difficult to enforce a limitation such as this one.

Comment: @Deimos - I've added a little more detail to my answer but I'm not sure that you'll be able to get a complete solution here in this format.

Comment: is the thankyou page of woocommerce section checkout, and via Ajax i send only information of the user, nothing like money, or like that,

Answer (score 1):

A better solution to avoid double submits, is to use a POST query for the submit request and let the server respond with a redirect to a normal (harmless) receipt/thankyou page.

Then if the user refreshes the receipt page they will simply repeat the GET request to the receipt page and not the post.

You should still add some checks server side to avoid multiple POST requests somehow (using sessions, timestamps or something), in case a malicious user deliberately tries to resubmit.

Comment: I assume that all users are malicious ;)

Comment: Yes. Though I usually assume a stupid but benevolent user when designing the clientside code and likely error messages. Every error likely caused by random stuff and user-incompetence should have a friendly  error message. Errors most likely caused by deliberate misuse or attacks could be served a simple and brutal "Unauthorized" or "Bad request" page. :)